# Python Insert Variables into String

Tags: python, regex

So i'm not great at regular expressions but i'd like to insert variables into a string. My string will look something like this (just a random example):

```
(%foo% * 3) / 2
```

And I would need to insert variables into it, %foo% being the name of the variable I need to use and might end up looking like this:

```
(4 * 3) / 2
```

I know I could do this using string formatting but each string may require different variables. Is there a good way that I can just create a regular expression that will swap out the placeholders with the variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) with named arguments:

```
>>> "{foo}, {bar}".format(foo=2, bar=4)
'2, 4'
```

Comment: Thankyou. If I parse values but they are not used would it error?

Comment: @CallumBonnyman it's ok: `"{foo}, {bar}".format(foo=2, bar=4, test=5)` would result into `2, 4` too.